# VBA: New (or Redefined?) Internet Explorer Object In Same Window

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I'm creating a macro that will navigate to a login page, log in, navigate to another page and scrape data, and then loop through 100-200 more pages scraping data from each.

So far I've gotten it to the point of logging in, navigating to the second page, and scraping the first bit of data. But so far the only way I can get it to work is if the second page opens in a new window. Since I ultimately have to go through 100-200 pages, I'd rather not use a new window for each one.

For this example let's just say that the only data I'm trying to scrape is the page title.

```
Option Explicit

Sub admin_scraper()

Dim ie As Object
Dim doc As Object    

' Get through log in page
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
With ie
    .navigate "http://example.com/login" 'Page title is "Page 1"
    .Visible = True
End With
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend
ie.document.forms(0).all("Username").Value = "user"
ie.document.forms(0).all("Password").Value = "abc123"
ie.document.forms(0).submit

'Navigate to second page and pull page title
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application") '***Line in question
With ie
    .navigate "http://example.com/Products" 'Page title is "Page 2"
    .Visible = True
End With
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

Set doc = ie.document

Debug.Print doc.Title

End Sub
```

*** If I include this line the code works as expected (console prints "Page 2"), but it opens the second page in a new window. If I don't include this line, the second page opens smoothly in the same window, but the console prints "Page 1."

Any way I can get it to open each new page in the same window while making sure it pulls data from the new page? Or if it has to be in a new window, any way to automatically close the old window each time?

Comment: You should try waiting after submitting the form, before navigating to the next page.

Comment: How would you go about that? If I try putting another Do While loop in there after submit and take out the second Set ie = CreateObject line, the rest of the code just never executes. It logs in and navigates to the second page in the window, but nothing ever prints to the console. Then when I manually close the Explorer window I get Run-time error '-[huge string of numbers]': Automation error Unspecified error.

Comment: its difficult to make a useful guess without access to the actual pages.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give that out. Why would the pages themselves affect that though? I'm just wondering if there is something other than `Set ie = CreateObject ("internetexplorer.application")` I can use to change the value of `ie` from the previous page to the new page without having to open a new Explorer window.

Comment: All you should need to do is add a "wiat" loop and then get a reference to the newly-loaded page using `Set doc = ie.document`: after any navigation your previous `doc` will still point to the previous (now unloaded) page, so you need to refresh that whenever the page reloads.

Comment: That's basically what I have now. Notice that after navigating to the second page I have a second `While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4 | DoEvents | Wend` loop, and then I set the `doc` variable after that (and that's actually the first time I set the `doc` variable at all). If I remove the second `ie = CreateObject` line, the visible window navigates to the second page in the same window no problem, but it still prints the title from the first page. If I leave that second `ie = CreateOject` line in there, the code functions as expected, but it uses a second window.

Comment: But if I try putting another `While` loop after the submit event, the rest of the code just never executes at all.

Comment: I can't account for that.  Instead of a loop (which for some reason may not be catching that the page has loaded) maybe try adding an `Application.Wait` for a few seconds and see if that works.